# Submitting the form after dropzone.js uploads all images

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone.js as part of a form all working as it should. I have it set so it doesn't process the upload queue until submit is clicked. But once it's uploaded all files I want it to submit the form. I've added the event in jQuery but it's still not submitting it.

What am I doing wrong here?

It gave me the success alert but didn't submit the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("div#dropzone").dropzone({ 
    url: "js/dropzone/upload.php",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    maxFilesize: 2,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    maxFiles: 10,
    init: function() {
      var myDropzone = this;
      $("#theform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        myDropzone.processQueue();
      });
    },
    completemultiple: function(file, response){
      alert("success");
      $("#theform").submit();
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: You probably have a typo here: `$("#theform").submit;`. It should be `$("#theform").submit();` -- note the parenthesis -- to `submit` method be called.

Comment: Good point, I changed it but it's still not having it.

Comment: This is because of what you're doing on submit -- preventDefault =))

Comment: I thought it might be, but I don't know how to fix it, hence why I'm on here.

Comment: You might set a flag if the form can be submitted, then decide if you need to preventDefault.

Answer (score 2):

You might set a flag if the form can be submitted, then decide if you need to preventDefault:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("div#dropzone").dropzone({ 
    url: "js/dropzone/upload.php",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    maxFilesize: 2,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    maxFiles: 10,
    init: function() {
      var myDropzone = this;
      $("#theform").submit(function(e) {
        if ($(this).prop('ready')) return true;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        myDropzone.processQueue();
      });
    },
    completemultiple: function(file, response){
      alert("success");
      $("#theform").prop('ready', true).submit();
    },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to work it out. I'm sure other people will have the same problem so here is the answer. You reverse the `e.preventDefault` and then click the submit button with jQuery once the queue is complete:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
  $("div#dropzone").dropzone({ 
    url: "js/dropzone/upload.php",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    maxFilesize: 2,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    maxFiles: 10,
    init: function() {
      var myDropzone = this;
      $("#theform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        myDropzone.processQueue();

      });
    },
    queuecomplete: function(file, response){
      $("#theform").unbind('submit').submit();
      $("#submit").click();
    },
  });
```